# IOS Button style

Tags: iphone, ios

Im looking for the following button in Xcode 4.
Please see the following link for an example. http://cascade-innovations.nl/image%208.png

But i cannot find it anywhere. Does anyone know how this button is called, or where i can find it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It's a `UITableViewCell` that was initialized with the `UITableViewCellStyleValue1` style.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a button. It's an `UITableViewCell` from an `UITableView`.

Answer (score 0):

You may thinking its button because clicking on it taking you to next screen

But it's uitableviewcell of 'grouped' uitableview